# mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've been checking on this error with no solutions specific to my code. I have connected to mysql server using the `mysqli_connect()` call. then passed the connection result to a `$_SESSION` to have it available over the whole website - as i normally do in all my other projects, But for some reason i keep getting the error:

```
"mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli"
```

There is the code that generates the error:

```
if(!isset($_GET['sortBy']))
    {
        $listSQL = "SELECT * FROM '".$_SESSION['WorkTable']."'";
    }
    else
    {
        $listSQL = "SELECT * FROM '".$_SESSION['WorkTable']."' where ".$_GET['sortBy']."='".$_GET['sortBy']."'";
    }

    //get Contacts From DB
    if(!empty(mysqli_query(@$_SESSION['IMWEDBcxn'],$listSQL)))
```

Here is the connection class code...

```
if(!empty($cxn))
{
    $_SESSION['WorkTable'] = $dbTable;

    $_SESSION['IMWEDBcxn'] = $cxn;
}
```

Anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Why is there the char @ before $_SESSION['IMWEDBcxn']? I know it's used to avoid warnings in functions but thats a variable used like the link of the connection of mysqli

Comment: You can't store connection handler in session, [it can not be serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php)

Comment: @Serpes ignore the '@'... was trying out some troubleshooting

Comment: Sometimes array variables are not works fine in query especially something like $v['something']; see those '' do something else just assign them to normal variables like $val=$v['something']; and do not forget sql injections.

Comment: @Ram Sharma why did you edit my code?there was nothing wrong with it? now its 'm ysqli_connect()' what is that? You wrong on the edit! Guys if you dont want to help don't say or do nothing...

Answer (score 2):

As stated by Ivan Solntsev, do not store a connection handler in a user's session for 2 obvious reasons :

1- Handlers can not be serialized.

2- Anything you store in a user's session (using `$_SESSION`), would only be available under that user's scope. I suggest you read more about sessions and PHP, `$_SESSION` is not a way to store data over sessions.

So doing something like :

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("...");
$_SESSION["dbconnection"] = $connect;

mysqli_query($_SESSION["dbconnection"], $query);
```

IS WRONG!

If you want a persistent connection, to avoid reconnecting on each DB query, read about MySQLi and Persistent connections : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php . If you are running on a PHP version under 5.3, I'd recommend using PDO (which I'd recommend regardless of the PHP version you're using).